# Встроенные функции Python

Tags: python

Как можно посмотреть исходный код встроенных функций?

Пробовал подключить модуль `inspect` и, вызывая функцию `getsource`, задавать в качестве параметра нужную мне функцию. Но метод заданного модуля отказался возвращать исходный код для встроенных функций, но, например, если скормить функции `getsource` функцию `print`, то ошибки не будет и я смогу получить то, что хотел.

Comment: на то они и встроенные функции. print долгое время также был встроенной функцией-оператором (не ручаюсь за точное определение).

В большинства таких функций исходный код не на питоне, а где то глубоко в с/с++ коде.

Comment: @KoVadim: `print` не был функцией в Питоне 2 (без `__future__`). `print()` в Питоне  3 является функцией (built-in function in CPython -- как в смысле, что не на чистом Питоне реализована, так и что в `__builtins__` пространстве имен находится).

Comment: я знаю, что print был не функцией - я же об этом написал. Но потом его решили сделать ею.

Answer (score 1):

Как написал KoVadim, многие встроенные функции питона написаны на C. Но, так как Python - язык с открытым исходным кодом, то исходники можно посмотреть [здесь](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3). Если интересна реализация тех же модулей на питоне, то советую посмотреть [исходники PyPy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy).

P.S. Чтобы узнать, какой файл относится к какому модулю, обычно можно посмотреть свойство `__file__`.

P.P.S. Есть [похожий](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8608587/3606603) вопрос на английском стэке.

Answer (score 1):

Фраза "built-in function" в сообщении об ошибке означает, что соответствующая функция реализована не на чистом Питоне:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import numpy
>>> inspect.getsource(print)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: <built-in function print> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
>>> inspect.getsource(numpy.array)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: <built-in function array> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

Очевидно, что `numpy.array` не является "встроенной функцией" в смысле принадлежности к [`__builtins__` пространству имён](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#builtins-and-restricted-execution), а является "встроенной функцией" в смысле "реализована не на чистом Питоне".

Исходный код подобных функций следует искать в соответствующих проектах: [CPython's `print()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/150e7769681a9e18b1df9a6e89f8c7298e2b9010/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1696-L1787), [Pypy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy), [Jython's `print()`](https://hg.python.org/jython/file/default/src/org/python/core/__builtin__.java#l1391), [`numpy.array()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/786f9c2f77b3ee4f90f5e26a2206f85087a415bc/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L1608-L1787), [`numpy` for Pypy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy).